# how to search string including with wildcart string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, wildcard

I'm developing a laravel api.i have some problem with string matching..
i have to match two database column values are in the same db table

EG: users table, SessionId and UserID

My sessionId like this,(With % wildcard string)

> adfdfvcfgfgfgfgfgbcd.%3d%f

UserId like this,

> 0001

When i implement a code matching this string always rerun null value.

But some sessionId not containing wildcard string and return all the correct details

This is my Usercontroller.php class show function

```
 public function show($id,$userid)

{
    try{

    $user=DB::table('users')->where('SessionId',$id)
                            ->where('UserId',$userid)
                            ->get();
        if(!$user)
        {
            return response()->json(['null'],404);
        }
        return $user;

    } catch (Exception $exception)
    {
        return response('something bad',500);
    }
}
```

and this is my routes.php class api url

```
    $api->version('v1',function ($api){
$api->get('One/{Id}/{UserId}',[
    'as'=>'user',
    'uses'=> '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@shower']);});
```

data store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user=new User;
      $user->SessionId=$request->input('SessionId');
      $user->UserId = $request->input('UserId');          
      if($user->save())
  {
      return $user;
  }

  throw  new HttpException(400,"Invalid data");
}
```

Comment: try this where('SessionId',"$id")

Comment: @Vishal nope,Same response

Comment: Are you sure you store the session id with the %? Maybe it is stored unescaped (e.g. `=` instead of `%3d`). Try to check the content of your rows in the database directly (and/or post the code that stores the id).

Comment: @Solarflare yeh you right sesssion id stored with %3d,i update my store data function see the last part .that is my store user session function